# Android Studio design screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been unable to find out why on some projects the design screen will not show up. I have noticed that the buttons code, split, and design are available when the .xml file is selected. On some projects, these buttons show up when the kotlin file is selected. Found answers that suggest to clean the project, rebuild  the project and clear the cache (actually says something else, but I can't remember what it was). Have tried all of those and and also reinstalled Android Studio as well. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank-you.

First time posting in here, not sure what else I can say.